# Multiple Expression in Tenary Operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I learnt about tenary operator recently from the JavaScript section of freecodecamp.org.

Now I'm trying to use it.

```js
var answer =prompt("Enter your answer here ");
return answer.toString().toLowerCase()===pool[i]["Answer"].toString().toLowerCase() ? scores++ : scores=scores
```

What I want, if true, is to increment var `scores` and also `console.log("Correct answer")` and if false, reassign the previous value of `scores` and `console.log("Wrong answer")`

Is there a way to achieve this with the tenary operator? Or should I just use the conventional `if-else` statements.

Comment: FYI `scores++` returns the value **before** incrementing

Comment: Then I better use `++scores`. And okay, I'd just use the if statement. Thank you @Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an `if {} else {}` if you want to do more than an assignment, such as a `console.log()`:

```
var answer = prompt("Enter your answer here ");
if(answer.toLowerCase() === pool[i]["Answer"].toLowerCase() {
  scores++;
  console.log("Correct answer");
} else {
  scores = previousScores;
  console.log("Wrong answer");
}
```

Notes:

- no need for `.toString()` because the prompt returns a string.
- I am not sure what you mean by "if false, reassign the previous value of scores", so I added a `previousScores` variable to represent that.

**UPDATE 1:** Technically it is possible to use a tenary operator with multiple statements, but it becomes unreadable as @Phil pointed out: `return condition ? (console.log("true"), "true value") : (console.log("false"), "false value")`

Comment: _"need"_ isn't exactly accurate... `return condition ? (console.log("true"), "true value") : (console.log("false"), "false value")`. Obviously this is less readable and therefore inferior however not impossible

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Peter. I had initiated `scores=0` somewhere and for corrects answers, `return ++scores;` but for wrong answers, `scores=scores`. And lastly, prompt return integers as string as well?

Comment: @AkintolaOluwaseyiAlex: No need for `scores = scores` if you don't want to change it. Yes, prompt always returns a string, also if the user enters a number, you can test it in the browser console: `typeof prompt('Enter a number:')`

Comment: @Phil: I updated the answer accordingly